# MySQL Database on my own computer

Tags: php, mysql, web-server

I am running Abyss Web Server on my personal computer and need to do some DB work with my website, but cannot access my actual hosting account with my hosting provider. Is there a way to kind of download mysql so i can do db work on localhost?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you [download mysql server community edition](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and install it.

Comment: :O I tried searching Bing and Google, and I kept getting results that lead me to MAMP, XAMP and lamp. - Thanks! I should've just gone straight to the mysql website before searching.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

Go to the MySQL website (you can find it by typing MySQL into Google) and click the Download link.

You will need to copy the database structure from the host, of course. They will probably provide you with an admin utility to do this. If they don't give you a pretty control panel with the feature, then a command line interface will give you access to the mysqldump utility.